# angular - is there any way to assign an array's value to a material table datasource?

Tags: angular, typescript

if I try `this.dataSource = this.array` where array is of type row, it throws the error type 'row[]' is missing properties from MaterialTableDataSource

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try assigning to data property of MatTableDataSource

```
this.dataSource.data = this.array
```